# Is it safe to add Spring 3.1 to the Tomcat\lib folder?

Tags: spring, tomcat

The current system I am working on uses Tomcat 7.0 and Spring 3.1 the system is a collection of web apps that all have the same classpath in WEB-INF\lib, I am thinking of adding spring 3.1 to my tomcat\lib so that all the web apps have access to it. Is this safe to do with Spring 3.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safe to add Spring 3.1 to the Tomcat main lib directory? Quite possibly. Good idea? Probably not; as the system administrator you'd be taking on the responsibility for ensuring that all the webapps can use that exact version of Spring (including all the issues that can crop up when you update things) because the webapps would not be able to override it to anything else. (To be fair, they could load classes from elsewhere that weren't in the standard system version you're proposing, but that's likely to be an extremely bad idea as there would be problems with warring versions of the same library. That's a *very* confusing situation to be in; avoid if at all possible!)

Comment: In my situation all the apps are forced to use the same exact classpath by design. so I am not worried about one app wanting a different class path than another app.

Comment: One important thing to mention (and may be this is not true for Tomcat 7, but I guess it is), I completely disagree with the upper comment, makes a lot of sense to use shared library "pattern"  for web applications BUT NEVER USE TOMCAT/lib, use TOMCAT/shared, that's the correct place.

Concerns about administration are not true, if use a shared folder configured as part of your distribution.

Besides this, not sure if there are any other concerns for spring regarding class-loader issues that might cause some problems when using it as a shared library.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule I only put very basic shared libraries like JDBC drivers in tomcat/lib.  Sharing other libraries will often lead to classloader issues in tomcat.  Unfortunately, I don't know the publish date of it, but you might find this article http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-classpath useful.